# What is The second rational number?

Tags: real-analysis

As we all know, rational number , let's suppose in the interval $[a,b]$, the rational number are countable,i.e.:
$$\exists \{q_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$$
be an enumeration of rational numbers[see Royden's real analysis page 70 Example about Dirichlet's function].

I have two questions:

1. if we suppose the sequence $q_k$ is increasing, obvious, the first number is $a$, what is the next number?
2. Is the function:$$f_n(x)=1,if\;x=q_k,1\leq k\leq n,and\;f(x)=0\;otherwise$$
   a step function by Royden's definition.

[From Royden real analysis edition 4th page 69]
A real-valued function $\psi$ defined on interval $[a,b]$ is called a **step function** provided there is a partition $P=\{x_0,x_1,..,x_n\}$ of $[a,b]$ and numbers $c_1,c_2,..,c_n$ such that for $1\leq i\leq n$,$$\psi(x)=c_i\;if\;x_{i-1}<x<x_i$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence $q_k$ *cannot* be increasing - between any two rationals, there is a third.

As to your second question, try graphing it . . .

EDIT: If you find this too abstract, suppose the enumeration begins

- $q_1=1$,
- $q_2=-2$,
- $q_3={7\over 9}$

(I'm just making up some concrete values to make it easier to picture). Graph $f_1, f_2,$ and $f_3$. Are these step functions? Why? Now, generalize.

Comment: Then at least $q_k$ can be non-decreasing, am I rigth?

Comment: @Benjamin No, it can't - it has to increase, and decrease, infinitely often. Try to prove this - it's a good exercise.

Comment: so do we have the second number in this sequence?

Comment: @Benjamin Well, it depends what you mean by "second" number. You have an enumeration of rationals - $q_1, q_2, q_3, . . .$. There's certainly a second element of this enumeration - namely, $q_2$. Since there are **lots** of enumerations of the rationals (uncountably many, in fact - exercise!), I don't know what $q_2$ is until you tell me some more information about the specific enumeration you're using. (cont'd)

Comment: So the **enumeration** has a second element. But, there will be rationals which are bigger than $q_1$ and smaller than $q_2$ (suppose $q_1<q_2$ for simplicity); they'll appear later on in the enumeration. For instance, maybe $q_1=1, q_2=7,$ and $q_{14123}={3\over 2}$. So in that sense, there is no "second" rational after $q_1$, because - given any rational $>q_1$ - there's a rational smaller than it, but still greater than $q_1$.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much. I'll try to prove the two exercises..